# String construction using OOP and Proxy pattern

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, sqlalchemy, proxy-pattern

I find it very interesting the way how SQLAlchemy constructing query strings, eg:

```
(Session.query(model.User)
        .filter(model.User.age > 18)
        .order_by(model.User.age)
        .all())
```

As far as I can see, there applied some kind of **Proxy Pattern**. In my small project I need to make similar string construction using OOP approach. So, I tried to reconstitute this behavior.

Firstly, some kind of object, one of plenty similar objects:

```
class SomeObject(object):
    items = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def __call__(self):
        return ' '.join(self.items) if self.items is not None else ''

    def a(self):
        self.items.append('a')
        return self

    def b(self):
        self.items.append('b')
        return self
```

All methods of this object return **self**, so I can call them in any order and unlimited number of times.

Secondly, proxy object, that will call subject's methods if it's not a **perform** method, which calls object to see the resulting string.

```
import operator

class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, some_object):
        self.some_object = some_object

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self.method = operator.methodcaller(name)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.some_object = self.method(self.some_object, *args, **kw)
        return self

    def perform(self):
        return self.some_object()
```

And finally:

```
>>> obj = SomeObject()
>>> p = Proxy(obj)
>>> print p.a().a().b().perform()
a a b
```

What can you say about this implementation? Is there better ways to make the desirable amount of classes that would make such a string cunstructing with **the same syntax**?

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my primary language.

Comment: Why don't you look at the SQLAlchemy code to see how they do this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually what you are looking at is not a proxy pattern but the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), and yes your implementation is IMHO is the classic one (using the [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern).

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not the builder pattern. Albeit in our days it is a common mistake to call it so. This is an example for an "internal DSL" or "fluent programming", the later term is the most widely used one. (The builder pattern is about constructing a graph of objects, where you want to seperate the algorithm of construction - the director - from the concrete created objects, e.g. Title, Abstract, Index, Chapter 1, Chapter 2 in a Document, which can be either a PDF document or an HTML one, etc.)

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere: Thank you for the detailed explanation, i didn't know that there is a difference between both pattern (builder vs fluent programming) but i have a question if i may: isn't the fluent programming (interface) a common way to implement the builder pattern, so maybe in this case we can say that the query is build using a builder pattern that implement the fluent interface ? thank you again for the extra knowledge :)

Comment: In the original GOF-Book the Builders whre not fluent if I recall correctly. I however always amde them fluent. To answer your question into a different direction: not all fluent "DSLs" have something to do with building. E.g. the FEST framework uses a fluent API for UI driven automatic tests (automatic mouse clicks etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what SQLAlchemy does, but I would implement the interface by having the `Session.query()` method return a `Query` object with methods like `filter()`, `order_by()`, `all()` etc.  Each of these methods simply returns a new `Query` object taking into account the applied changes.  This allows for method chaining as in your first example.

Your own code example has numerous problems. One example

```
obj = SomeObject()
p = Proxy(obj)
a = p.a
b = p.b
print a().perform()  # prints b
```